# Laravel + Hyn Tenancy + Spatie Permission, Role Admin in respective Dashboard

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-permission

good morning to everyone, I will comment on the situation to see if you can give me an idea ...

I am using Hyn Tenancy (Saas) and Spatie Permissions

Currently I have the whole system working without problems and it is as follows:

Users can log in to domain.com or sub1.domain.com or sub2.domain.com and from either enter their account and the session is shared.

and a general dashboard where it shows a history of your purchases in any subdomain.

so far so good ...

Now create the dashboard for the admins ... which is accessed from sub1.domain.com/admin

the problem I have is that everyone who is admin can enter but I only need admin1 to enter sub1.domain.com/admin

admin2 to sub2.domanin.com/admin

Any can help me plz?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you can't share any code with community.
So with experience in laravel permission and your senario as I know you want each subdomain wit an admin have only access to his/her subdomain admin area.
you should create a new gate or middleware or in your gate for admins define an if to check if the user is a member of subdomain?
in laravel permission only administrators explited from other users and you should define new gate or middleware and add it to admin route definition.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i use a uuid from subdomain... and compare with a user uuid... if correct it show the forms, else search the uuid in a subdomain and redirect it to our domain.

Thanks you!